# Какого рода и числа "ясли-сад", например, "Клепачские(й) ясли-сад"?

Tags: склонение

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ясли- сад - это сложное существительное.Да, у Аванесова есть конкретный пример употребления этого сложного существительного. Новые ясли - сад. Т.е. это существительное имеет форму множественного числа (как часы,сутки, например), род у таких существительных не определяется.

Общие рекомендации найдем у Розенталя:

"При согласовании сказуемого со сложными существитель-
ными, образующими сложносоставные термины типа кафе-столовая,
учитываются смысловые отношения между частями сложного слова:

ведущим компонентом, с которым согласуется сказуемое, является
то слово, которое выражает более широкое понятие или конкретно
обозначает предмет, например: кафе-столовая отремонтирована
(столовая — более широкое понятие); автомат-закусочная открыта
(носителем конкретного значения выступает слово закусочная);

кресло-кровать стояло в углу (мыслится один из видов кресел, вто-
рая часть выступает в роли уточняющей); плащ-палатка лежала
в свернутом виде (палатка в виде плаща, а не плащ в виде палатки."

В существительном "Ясли-сад" обе части по смыслу равноправны, согласование идет с ближайшей частью слова.

Answer (score 0):

На первый вгляд, ясли-сад в смысле детский сад. Значит,"ясли-сад " мужского рода ед. ч. Но если слово "сад" - приложение, то главным должно быть слово "ясли". В Толковом cловаре  Ефремовой это слово мн.ч. А здесь http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/ это  м. р.
Я склоняюсь ко 2 варианту. 
P.S. Если "детские ясли", то обычно так и говорят. Без слова "сад". Или "ясельная группа детского сада"

Comment: >ясли-сад в смысле детский сад  
  
В смысле "детские ясли", нет?!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что смотреть надо не в толковых словарях, а в орфоэпических. 
Тем более - не в свободном от всякой ответственности Вики-словаре.
Аванесов даёт "новые ясли сад". Причем склоняет оба слова, что тоже абсолютный аргумент в пользу главенства "яслей".